# Spring Constant and Second Derivative

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, differentiation, spring

According to my book the spring constant is given by $k=V''(X_o)$. Where $V(X)$ is the potential energy function. if I use the function $V(X)=X^6+X^4$ the spring constant is zero at $X_o=0$. However, the plot looks like a stable equilibrium that would allow harmonic oscillation near $X_o$. So why is $k$ zero in this case?

Comment: Might appreciate [this](http://www2.chem.umd.edu/groups/alexander/chem691/Quartic_oscillator.pdf).

Comment: The  conserved energy is $E= \dot x ^2/2+ x^4 +x^6 $, so some type of "parabola" in the squares of the displacement and the velocity in phase space, a periodic motion--behold! So you should *define* an analog of the  restoring constant in this nonlinear system, in the suitable quadratic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force is given by the first derivative of the potential:
\begin{equation}
F(X) = - \frac{d}{dX}V(X) = -6X^5 -4X^3.
\end{equation}
At small displacements, i.e. when $X\ll 1$ we have $X^5 \ll X^3$, that is the returning force is proportional to $X^3$ and not to $X$, as is in the case of a harmonic oscillator. The *spring constant* is indeed zero.

You are right that there are oscillations in this case, however these oscillations are not harmonic. Your logic based on the shape of the potential energy is a sound one and is used for analyzing *nonlinear oscillators*, such as the one that you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Periodic motion is not the same as being a harmonic oscillator. A harmonic oscillator describes the very particular force configuration F=-kx, where k is the spring constant, and this is not the force for the potential you propose. Therefore, there need not be an equivalent of a spring constant just because the motion is periodic. For example, a particle bouncing around an infinite square potential well would exhibit periodic motion, but not oscillation.